# Error Using django-tables2 - Expected table or queryset, not 'str'

Tags: python-2.7, django-1.7, django-tables2

I am trying to create some tables for my application using django-tables2 and running into some difficulties. I am using Python 2.7, and Django 1.7. I am following the tutorial, and I ran into problems.

I reach the point where I need to create a Table class for customization. However, whenever I do so, I get the following error:

> Expected table or queryset, not 'str'.

After doing [some](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/iq2XB7wVgLs) [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412003/haystack-django-tables2-expected-table-or-queryset-not-str) it looks like I am using an older version of django-tables2. However, I just installed it yesterday using `pip install django-tables2` and updated it a half an hour ago. Any idea how I can get django-tables2 to work properly?

**EDIT -**  Problem solved. I was using `{% render_table people %}` instead of `{% render_table table %}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I encountered that problem, too. The first thing you should do is to check your updates:

```
sudo pip install django-tables2 --upgrade
sudo pip install django-tables2-reports --upgrade
```

Upgrades didn't fix my problem either.
If you have already upgraded version of these. You should check your implementation. If you are using Class Based View and you probably implemented the view,template,table. You probably forget the urls:

```
/* I give the example with respect to other post*/
urls.py  /*Same dic with table.py,models..etc*/

from .views import SomeTableView   
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   url(r"^$", SomeTableView.as_view(), name="index"),

                   
                   )
```

If it is not index of your website you have to probably change the `r"^$"` and `name="index"`

Answer (score 13):

Well I think your problem isn't with the version of django-tables2. Here I think when you are passing a variable from view to template, you are passing a string instead of a queryset/table class object. For working example:

Table class:

```
class SomeTable(tables.Table):
    
    class Meta:
        model= SomeModel
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}
```

View Class:

```
                                       # Important part!!!!
class SomeTableView(SingleTableView):  # <-- check for SingleTableView
    model = SomeModel
    template_name = 'test.html'
    table_class = SomeTable
```

Template:

```
 {% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
 {% render_table table %}   <!-- Here I am passing table class -->
```

Or you can directly send a queryset to render the table like:

```
class SomeView(TemplateView):
     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         data = SomeModel.objects.all()
         context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context['table'] = data
         return self.render_to_response(context)
```

and render it like this:

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% render_table table %} <!-- Here I am passing queryset -->
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem. I forgot to add `SingleTableMixin` in the parameters of the view class

Comment: Similar to what [Sharpless512](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1346462/sharpless512) said, but in my case, I forgot to update my view from `ListView` to `SingleTableView`

Comment: that really helped :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [django-tables2 documentation](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html):
In *tutorial/views.py*, the class name is `PersonListView`
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/949HF.jpg)

I changed the class name from `PersonListView` to `PersonTableView`
And also made the this change in *urls.py*.

My problem was solved by doing this.

Why was this problem caused?
Please anyone let me know.