# Error "Expected table or queryset, not str " for form

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I am building a private website for inventory management using python django, and i was creating a form to add items in my **Item** Model, till now I have redone my form code 2-3 times but am always getting stuck with same error "Expected table or queryset, not str" and have run out of ideas.
here is my code,

> views.py:
>
> ```
> from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
> from django.http import HttpResponse
> from .models import Item, Tender
> from django.urls import reverse
> from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
> from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
> from django.contrib import messages
> from .forms import NewUserForm, AddItemForm
> from .tables import ItemTable
>
>
> def item_list(request):
>     table = ItemTable(Item.objects.all())
>
>     return render(request, "main/item_list.html", {
>         "table": table
>     })
>
> def add_item(request):
> if request.method == 'POST':
>     form = AddItemForm(request.POST)
>     if form.is_valid():
>         Item = form.save(commit = False)
>         Item.item_updated = timezone.now()
>         Item.save()
>         return redirect("main:item_list")
>
> else:
>     form = AddItemForm()
>
>
> return render(request, "main/item_list.html", {'form': form})
> ```

> models.py:
>
> ```
> from django.db import models
> from datetime import datetime
> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>
> class Item(models.Model):
>     item_no = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key = True )
>     item_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
>     item_quantity = models.CharField(max_length = 200, default = 0)
>     item_description = models.TextField(blank = True)
>     item_updated = models.DateTimeField("Item updated", default=datetime.now())
>     item_price = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default = 0)
>
>     def __str__(self):
>         return self.item_name
> ```

> forms.py:
>
> ```
> from django import forms
> from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
> from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
> from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
> from .models import Item
> from datetime import datetime
>
> class AddItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
>
>     class Meta:
>         model = Item
>         fields = (
>             'item_no', 'item_name', 'item_quantity', 'item_description', 'item_price'
>         )
> ```

> add_item.html:
>
> ```
> {% extends "main/header.html" %}
>
>     {% block content %}
>         <h1>Add Item Form</h1>
>
>         <form method="POST" class="post-form">
>             {% csrf_token %}
>             {{form.as_p}}
>             <button class="btn" type="submit">Add Item</button>
>         </form>
>
>     {% endblock %}
> ```

> urls.py:
>
> ```
> from django.urls import path
> from . import views
>
> app_name = "main"
>
> urlpatterns = [
>     path("", views.homepage, name="homepage"),
>     path("register/", views.register, name="register"),
>     path("logout/", views.logout_request, name="logout"),
>     path("login/", views.login_request, name="login"),
>     path("item_list/", views.item_list, name="items"),
>     path("tender/", views.tender, name="tender"),
>     path("add_item/", views.add_item, name="add_item"),
>
>
> ]
> ```

> tables.py:
>
> ```
> import django_tables2 as tables
> from .models import Item
>
> class ItemTable(tables.Table):
>     class Meta:
>         model = Item
> ```

> item_list.html:
>
> ```
> {% extends "main/header.html" %}
> {% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
>
>   {% block content %}
>     <a href = "/add_item" class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons left">add_circle</i>Add Item</a>
>     {% render_table table %}
>
>   {% endblock %}
> ```

> stack trace:
>
> File
> "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
> in inner
> 34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
> "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
> in _get_response
> 126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
> "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
> in _get_response
> 124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\ASUS\mysite\main\views.py" in add_item
> 88.     return render(request, "main/item_list.html", {'form': form})
>
> File
> "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py"
> in render
> 36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
>
> File
> "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages\django\template\loader.py"
> in render_to_string
> 62.     return template.render(context, request)
>
> File
> "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py"
> in render
> 61.             return self.template.render(context)
>
> File
> "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
> in render
> 171.                     return self._render(context)
>
> File
> "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
> in _render
> 163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File
> "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
> in render
> 937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File
> "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
> in render_annotated
> 904.             return self.render(context)
>
> File
> "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py"
> in render
> 150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)
>
> File
> "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
> in _render
> 163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File
> "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
> in render
> 937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File
> "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
> in render_annotated
> 904.             return self.render(context)
>
> File
> "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py"
> in render
> 62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File
> "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
> in render
> 937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File
> "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
> in render_annotated
> 904.             return self.render(context)
>
> File
> "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages\django_tables2\templatetags\django_tables2.py"
> in render
> 145.             raise ValueError("Expected table or queryset, not {}".format(klass))
>
> Exception Type: ValueError at /add_item/ Exception Value: Expected
> table or queryset, not str

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: can you share your full stack trace?

Comment: Most probably this error is due to django-tables package. Try updating django-tables to latest version as mentioned here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29683290/error-using-django-tables2-expected-table-or-queryset-not-str

Comment: I checked my django-tables is up to date

Answer (score 0):

your error seems to be happening when you try to render "item_list.html".

```
File "C:\Users\ASUS\mysite\main\views.py" in add_item 88. return render(request, "main/item_list.html", {'form': form})
```

And that's the one file that you don't seem to have provided :)

Incidentally, the problem is in how you are you are using the django_tables2 library.  I'm not familiar with django_tables2, but from that part of the stack trace

```
File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages\django_tables2\templatetags\django_tables2.py" in render 145. raise ValueError("Expected table or queryset, not {}".format(klass))
```

It appears that you're passing a string to some tag that "expects a table or queryset"

Comment: I have added item_list.html code, I have looked it over but could not find the problem.

Comment: Gosh, that looks like it matches the documentation.  I'm not sure I can be of more help.